# sql query fun calc once for table

Tags: r, sql-server

Trying to create a function to return data from a database. When used in the table, it works only on the first row.

```
> library(RODBC)
> f1 <- function(p){return (paste(p, "+", sep=""))}
> f2 <- function(p){
  h <- odbcConnect("dsn")
  r <- sqlQuery(h, paste("select '", p, "' + '+'", sep=""))
  return (r[1])
}

> x <- data.frame(p = c("a", "b"))
> data.frame(x, p2 = f1(x$p))
  p p2
1 a a+
2 b b+

> data.frame(p = x$p, p2 = f2(x$p))
  p Var.2
1 a    a+
2 b    a+
Warning message:
In data.frame(p = x$p, p2 = f2(x$p)) :
  имена строк взяты из короткой переменной и поэтому сброшены
>
```

Please give me an explanation of what I am doing wrong. 
Thanks

Ilya

Comment: It makes no sense to vectorize a SQL query the way you have done it.  Can you tell us what exact SQL you are trying to generate?

Comment: I am trying to define a sql function for example the price of an article

Comment: There isn't enough information here.  Provide input values and desired output.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: > data.frame(p = x$p, p2 = f2(x$p))
  p Var.2  <<== p2
1 a    a+  <<== Ok
2 b    a+  <<== b+

Comment: in case f1 is Ok: a+, b+  But in f2(via sql) : a+ and a+ !

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to do something like this:

```
f2 <- function(p){
  # c("a", "b") -->> "('a'), ('b'), (NULL)"
  s <- paste(<summary>_paste("('", p, "'),", sep=""), " (NULL)", sep = "")
  # ms sql
  qry <- paste("select x + '+' as p from values(", s, ")t(x) where x is not NULL", sep = "")
  odbcConnect(..)
  return(sqlQuery(h, qry))
}
```